# Why is it 'a ticket _to_ the cinema' but 'a ticket _for_ a/the concert'?

Tags: prepositions

I wonder if there is any difference in meaning between prepositions 'to' and 'for' in the examples above, if that is the case, what is it? Are they interchangeable?

I have checked the site for similar questions - still not satisfied with the explanation that preposition 'to' indicates direction while 'for' is used to talk about admission into a certain place.

Answer (score 1):

Tickets **to** are more often used for venues and tickets **for** for events although usage is also largely idiomatic and they prepositions are often interchangeable.

So you would generally buy a ticket **for** the concert, event, movie, bus, train and the like.

And you would obtain a ticket to (enter) the cinema, hall, stadium and grounds.

If you play board games or listen to the Beetles you may well be familiar with the expression **ticket to ride**, which has become idiomatic in a number of contexts.